# Is there anyway to send email to a list of contact?

Tags: api, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Is there anyway to send email to a list of contact? I can't find any api docs about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending an email with SendGrid you can send to one or multiple email addresses, and you can do so via the `to`, `cc`, and/or `bcc` fields.

When you send an email via SendGrid, you do so using "personalizations". [According to the documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send), personalizations are:

> An array of messages and their metadata. Each object within personalizations can be thought of as an envelope - it defines who should receive an individual message and how that message should be handled.

An example of an array of personalizations might look like this:

```js
[
    {
      to: [
        {
          email: 'john_doe@example.com',
          name: 'John Doe'
        },
        {
          email: 'julia_doe@example.com',
          name: 'Julia Doe'
        }
      ],
      cc: [
        {
          email: 'jane_doe@example.com',
          name: 'Jane Doe'
        }
      ],
      bcc: [
        {
          email: 'james_doe@example.com',
          name: 'Jim Doe'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      from: {
        email: 'sales@example.com',
        name: 'Example Sales Team'
      },
      to: [
        {
          email: 'janice_doe@example.com',
          name: 'Janice Doe'
        }
      ],
      bcc: [
        {
          email: 'jordan_doe@example.com',
          name: 'Jordan Doe'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

In the above example, one email is sent to two different people, John Doe and Julia Doe, cc'd to Jane Doe and bcc'd to Jim Doe. An email with the same content is also sent from a different email address (sales@example.com) to Janice Doe and bcc'd to Jordan Doe.

Hopefully you can see that specifying the recipients of an email is very flexible and you can send to many people at the same time.

Check out [the documentation and code examples for sending emails with SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send) for more information.

Comment: I mean I want to send just the message and subject, but let Sendgrid select recipients from specific list of contacts.

Comment: Ah, then yes. You’re looking for [SendGrid marketing campaigns](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-email-with-marketing-campaigns) where you can add contacts, segment them, and send emails.

Comment: Marketing campaigns seem not have and API to send campaign email?
Like dynamic template one

Comment: You can send emails to contacts via the [single send API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/create-single-send).

Comment: Awesome, would you mind marking the answer as correct so that other people can see it helped too? Thanks!